What color is my house?
I woke up this morning at five past nine and arrived at my job just south of DC via train. I spent a few hours working, ate lunch, then headed back out through the garage and took my ten-minute break. I decided I would smell some roses, and I had a very nice chat with the nearby man in blue who must've had the same idea. After saying goodbye and working some more, I ate dinner and worked for another few hours, then decided to go home by carpooling with a friend I ran into in the garage. When I got home, I collected my paycheck and then fell asleep.
That's an average day for me. It begs the question though: what color is my house?
Not part of the puzzle. First question submission! I have no idea how easy/hard this will be to solve; good luck!

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Great first puzzle! Hope too see more :)

Brilliant puzzle, and welcome to PSE!

@BlueHerring Your username is perfect to comment on this question :-)

One of the most creative I've seen in a good while!

Your house is the color:

GREEN!

In fact, here is a picture of your house!

 

Because

This is about the US monopoly board - and houses in monopoly are green!




Lets break down your day:

I woke up this morning at five past nine and arrived at my job just south of DC via train.


This puzzle will involve taking the numbers as moves.

First is 5, moving you to Reading Railroad, from which you catch the train.

You then moved 9 spaces and arrived at 'Virginia Avenue' (perhaps getting off the train at Pennsylvania Railroad) - and Virginia is just south of DC.



Five past nine is also = 14, and the Virginia Avenue is the 14th location on the board


I spent a few hours working, ate lunch, then headed back out through the garage and took my ten-minute break.


You 'ate lunch' or in monopoly terms, moved eight ('ate') spaces landing on chance. You then got sent back 3 spaces going through the garage - aka 'Free Parking':




I decided I would smell some roses, and I had a very nice chat with the nearby man in blue who must've had the same idea.


The '10 minute break' from before moves you 10 spaces to 'Marvin Gardens', where you could smell some roses, and you chatted to the police officer in blue next door:




After saying goodbye and working some more, I ate dinner and worked for another few hours, then decided to go home by carpooling with a friend I ran into in the garage.


You 'ate' again, moving eight spaces more around the board, landing on 'Park Place' where your friend's car was parked, and then went "home" aka the 'GO' square.



Your friend's car also probably looks like this:




When I got home, I collected my paycheck and then fell asleep


You collected your salary of $200 and completed your day - as in you completed a complete cycle around the board!




You've got most of it, to the point that I will accept. There is a bit more hidden within (it does have to do with the eating, and some of the specific phrasing used!)

I actually didn't consider KFC (though that is now a humorous mental image). What I was really referring to was rot13: eryngvat gb gur snpg gung lbh ernyvmrq svir naq avar znqr sbhegrra. ner gurer nal bgure ahzoref gung lbh pbhyq hfr gb zbir nybat gur obneq gb gur fcnprf lbh zragvbarq?

I still don't believe you have everything! Unfortunately, rot13: gur tneqra vf avar fcnprf sebz gur tnentr, abg gra. Vs bayl gurer jnf n jnl gb tb onpx guebhtu gur tnentr gb ynaq ba gur cerivbhf fcnpr orsber zbivat gra... Naq ubj znal fcnprf sebz Ivetvavn jbhyq gung yvr? Vf gung ahzore nyyhqrq gb fbzrjurer...?

Not to help where it isn't wanted but... rot13: "Ngr yhapu" nf va zbirq rvtug... gura punapr gbbx lbh onpx guerr fb gung lbh pbhyq zbir "onpx guebhtu" gur pnecnex (serr cnexvat) n jubyr gra fcnprf? Yngre n frpbaq "ngr qvaare" jbhyq zbir lbh rvtug gb "cnex cynpr" juvpu zvtug or n qvssrerag ersrerapr gb n pnecnex..?

@Graylocke ah yep thats what I'm missing, thanks!

@ilikecorgis I believe I finally now how everything, thanks to help from Graylocke :P

Ding ding ding! That looks like all to me! (besides the fact that rot13: svir fcnprf ynaqf ba gur Ernqvat envyebnq orsber gur avar ynaqvat ba Ivetvavn (gnxvat gur genva). )

@ilikecorgis Oh wow I hadn't even realised that - just thought the 14 was one move (which obviously makes no sense now I think about it when the max is 12 :P)

(trggvat bs gur genva) is a minor typo.

@Wyck good catch, fixed

Not a real answer, but surprisingly (or maybe not?) it matches @Beastly Gerbil's (correct) answer!

Your house is green! Taking the six numbers mentioned in your story, in order as hex values in RGB gives us 598108, which is a color that very closly matches the house color in Monopoly - so maybe it is not a coincidence after all!




That is hilarious- and completely unintentional!

Added a picture for reference, funny find!

I mean... rot13(vg'f grpuavpnyyl pbeerpg).

@BeastlyGerbil: I think your photo is showing the color using rot13: qrpvzny inyhrf engure guna urk. Juvyr fgvyy gur fnzr pbybe, gur urk inyhrf frrzf pybfre gb lbhe bevtvany nafjre.

@BlueHerring: rot13: Gur orfg xvaq bs pbeerpg!
